# How do I post text and image to a facebook page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, share

I've been poring through the FB Javascript SDK all day long but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this done. I'm successfully using

```
FB.ui(
{
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
})
```

to share a post that has a card attached. However, I would now like to create a post on a page that I manage WITHOUT the card. I would like to create a photo (with a caption) and text in the post. I see this happening in 3 steps:

1. Open a FB dialog box to select the page I want to post to
2. Post the image (with caption) to facebook
3. Create the page post with the attached image and text

So far, it seems like I could use something like this to create the post:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  name: 'Test Name',
  link: "http://192.168.1.149/", 
  picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
})
```

However, I can't do anything until I first figure out how to select a page to post to. Can anyone offer some guidance on where I go from here?

Comment: I've got to believe that FB's docs would cover this.

Comment: It might, but if it did I couldn't find / didn't understand it. If you find anything, please let me know

Comment: you need to provide the data with open graph tags, in the url you want to share.

Comment: You can not post to a page using the Feed dialog. It is possible using the Share dialog, but the user will have to select to post to a page they manage manually.